# Masking netcdf file with shapefile using GeoPandas Python

Tags: intersection, netcdf, shapefile, geopandas, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file of the EDGAR emission inventory and a shapefile of the US Census data. I want to extract the data from the netcdf that only overlaps/intersects with the NYC region in the entire shapefile so then I can calculate the total emissions in NYC.

- Shapefile is 2018 US Census cartographic Boundary Files for Urban Areas.
  https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_ua10_500k.zip
- Netcdf file is EDGAR Emission inventories for N2O in 2015.
  https://edgar.jrc.ec.europa.eu/gallery.php?release=v50&substance=N2O&sector=TOTALS

I have never worked with shapefiles/GeoPandas so bear with me. I am able to read in the shapefile, filter for specific region, then convert netcdf to GeoDataFrame. **I want to only keep the data from the netcdf that falls within the filtered region from the shapefile in order to do analysis**.

Update: I tried using `sjoin` and `clip` but when I execute that command, my dataframes have no data and when I plot with `sjoin`, I get an error "*The GeoDataFrame you are attempting to plot is empty. Nothing has been displayed.*"

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal,osr,ogr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr


# read in file path for shapefile
fp_shp = "C:/Users/cb_2018_us_ua10_500k/cb_2018_us_ua10_500k.shp"
# read in netcdf file path
ncs = "C:/Users/v50_N2O_2015.0.1x0.1.nc"

# Read in NETCDF as a pandas dataframe
# Xarray provides a simple method of opening netCDF files, and converting them to pandas dataframes
ds = xr.open_dataset(ncs)
edgar = ds.to_dataframe()

# the index in the df is a Pandas.MultiIndex. To reset it, use df.reset_index()
edgar = edgar.reset_index()

# Read shapefile using gpd.read_file()
shp = gpd.read_file(fp_shp)

# read the netcdf data file
#nc = netCDF4.Dataset(ncs,'r')

# quick check for shpfile plotting
shp.plot(figsize=(12, 8));

# filter out shapefile for SPECIFIC city/region

# how to filter rows in DataFrame that contains string
# extract NYC from shapefile dataframe
nyc_shp = shp[shp['NAME10'].str.contains("New York")]

# export shapefile
#nyc_shp.to_file('NYC.shp', driver ='ESRI Shapefile')

# use geopandas points_from_xy() to transform Longitude and Latitude into a list of shapely.Point objects and set it as a geometry while creating the GeoDataFrame
edgar_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(edgar, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(edgar.lon, edgar.lat))

print(edgar_gdf.head())

# check CRS coordinates
nyc_shp.crs #shapefile
edgar_gdf.crs #geodataframe netcdf

# set coordinates equal to each other
# PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs
edgar_gdf.crs = nyc_shp.crs

# check coordinates after setting coordinates equal to each other
edgar_gdf.crs #geodataframe netcdf

# Clip points, lines, or polygon geometries to the mask extent.
mask = gpd.clip(edgar_gdf, nyc_shp)
```

Comment: I apologise I don't have the time to write a good answer but give a look at regionmask: https://regionmask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @MatteoDeFelice - I changed my question; is there a way I can approach this problem by only using GeoPandas and intersection? I have a specific region and I'm not sure if regionmask has the clear boundaries defined from the US Census data I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I need to make sure my netcdf file has the same longitude degrees as my shapefile. So instead of [0, 360] I converted it to be [-180, 180] to match before converting into a GeoDataFrame. Then the above code works!